# Ajax $.post with document.ready in success

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]Hi I am running an AJAX Post to my PHP url and when done I am returning a document.ready function with my appended jQuery page.

I want to make sure if I am doing this correctly when placing the function in the success part of my AJAX post. It will not work at the minute. Any help would be great?

```
 function loadJobRequests() {

    / /AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/json-data- 
                 jobrequests.php",
           data: { userEmail: localStorage.getItem("email") }, 
           cache: false,
           success: function() {
            $(document).ready(function(){
```

I just need to find out if i have to pass any parameters into the function at success and then same same parameter into document.ready. Thanks

Comment: There is no document.ready event for an Ajax call.... That only would be fired when browser loads.

Comment: Put the code that calls `loadJobRequests()` inside `$(document).ready()`. You don't need to do it in the success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, you shouldn't use `$(document).ready(...)` here. The function you put inside that is only executed at the moment the DOM is first "readied", shortly after page load - this will be long since past by the time your script has been loaded, executed, fired an Ajax call and then returned the response (all of which needs to happen before your `success` callback happens).

But the very reason that `$(document).ready(...)` doesn't work also means that you don't need it here. The only reason it's used is to make sure that any DOM elements you refer to (typically to attach event handlers to) actually exist and the point this code is executed. Since the "ready" event has long since fired by the time the Ajax response comes in, the DOM will accurately reflect the current content of the page, and you can safely do whatever you want to manipulate it.

So whatever function you were going to put inside there, just put directly in the `success` callback.

Comment: I have attached image in my question explaining what I need to do. I want to getJson and append page. This page all is working fine on it's own, I just want to append it now to the success function.